# Looking for powershell solution to convert/scale tif images to jpeg

Tags: powershell, imagemagick, scale, imagemagick-convert

I want to re-scale TIFF images to JPEGs at 500 pixels across. 
My script below can convert .jpg into a scaled .jpg within a local drive but not across a server. What am I missing for it to work?

```
Get-ChildItem -path $source -filter *.tif | % { convert $_.Name -scale 500 "$($_.BaseName)-scaled.jpg" }
```

If I try to work across a network I get the error:

```
convert.exe: unable to open image "....jpg": No such file or directory
```

I also can't seem to convert .tif to .jpg in this way. Is there a way around both of these issues?

Comment: can you run the command manually for a single file? This sounds like it may be more of an ImageMagic issue than a PowerShell issue.

Comment: Can you confirm you got this working? if so can you close or write your own answer and marked it answered?

Comment: @Nick: The issue is not resolved because I can't get the script to convert jpeg to tiff on a server. I can only get jpeg to jpeg on a local drive.

Comment: Most likely @TheMadTechnician is right and it's not powershell having problems but your `convert.exe`. Try creating a mapped drive to the network folder and retry the script. 10 to 1 that will work and confirm the hypothesis.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician for some reason the issue is with $_.Name and $($_.BaseName). I changed these to $_.FullName and $($_.FullName) respectively and the process works. However I am left with names that look like image.tif-scaled.jpg. How do i remove the ".tif" to get "*-scaled.jpg"?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a partial solution:

```
Get-ChildItem -path $source -filter *.tif | % { convert $_.FullName -scale 500 "$($_.BaseName)-scaled.jpg" }
```

However, the rescaled images are placed where the ps1 script is located.

Comment: Replace `"$($_.BaseName)-scaled.jpg"` with `"$($_.FullName -Replace ".tif+$", "-scaled.jpg")"`